# How to connect to network printer with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-printer

Network printer is legacy HP LaserJet 6MP, plugged into a Windows XP workstation that is acting as our network share and the gateway to our shared storage devices. Others @ office are using the printer fine. I'm running a fresh install of Win7x64, can't for the life of me get this working.

Test page from printer does NOT show IP address, so I'm using the Wizard:

1. Devices and Printers
2. Add a printer
3. Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer
4. The printer that I want isn't listed
5. Select a shared printer by name > browse
6. Server computer does NOT show up in the network list
7. But if I manually type the server name \servername it shows up, and I can see the printers connected to it.
8. Select the printer I want to connect to
9. Next. I get the "Connecting to PrinterName on ServerName" dialog.
10. No driver found error dialog
11. Press OK. Get the Browse dialog box that says "The file "*.INF" on (Unknown) is needed.
12. I browse to the exact driver I need for that exact printer, which is extracted to my hard drive. Locate the "prnhp001.Inf" file > OK

Error dialog: Windows cannot connect to the printer. Error code is 0x0214

Comment: There's no such thing as a Windows XP server. XP is a workstation OS.

Comment: Fine. Updated the OP. The computer that acts as our network share and to which the printer is connected is a windows XP workstation.

Comment: If I had to guess, you're trying to connect from your 64-bit Windows 7 workstation to a printer installed on a *32-bit* Windows XP installation and you're trying to install the 32-bit drivers. You need 64-bit drivers for a 64-bit client.

Comment: @RobM I think architecture had something to do with it. The drivers I had (Microsoft driver update for HP LaserJet 6P-6MP PostScript) had a subfolder called Ia64. I located another similarly titles .cab but it expanded to reveal a folder called AMD64. That driver worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drivers that I had were 32-bit drivers, and my system architecture was x64. Once I located the appropriate 64-bit drivers, they were able to install without too much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing a network printer choose local printer , than add standard tcp/ip port and enter the printers IP address.

That's It !

Comment: LaserJet 6 doesn't have a network interface, it won't even take a JetDirect card. Thus, it can't have an IP address.

Comment: I also mention in my OP that I cannot determine the printer's IP address in the test page.

Comment: You can't determine the printer's IP address *because it doesn't have one.*

Comment: @mfinni Got it lol

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make sure both machines are on the same workgroup.
Right-Click --> My Computer --> Properties

Second, you could type in the XP machines address like so `\\192.168.0.101\`
The ending slash will find any available attached drives, or hardware for use.

Third, be sure network and sharing are turned on for the XP machine sharing the printer.
http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/winxpnetworking/ht/winxpsfs.htm